# (PHP) Checking if a field is empty in a database query call and output data if it isn't

Tags: php, database, search, extract

I'm putting together a database query for a search engine where you can specify whether the row should have an imagestring or not in the result. In the database this field will be empty if there is no image, or it will have a random image name (*e.g. 1238791.jpg*). When I construct the query string I check every field and add onto the string what is requested in the search.

For example, if the "Username" field is filled out, it will add `"AND username LIKE '%$searchUsername%'"` to the string as an example. However, I'm not sure how to proceed to find out if there is an image (Checking for NULL won't work here) since if there **is** an image I need to extract the **name** of the image so I can use it or print it out in the results.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Probably me being forgetful, but why wouldn't `if == ""` work?

Comment: You're trying to make the image field searchable? Eg. "return rows where imagefield has '1238791.jpg' in it AND the username field contains "joe"?

Comment: I presume it might, but I'm a little clouded on how to proceed to extract the field's string-contents if it's not null.

Comment: @ Marc B - No, that's not my intention. In the search form you are asked if you want images to be required in the search query with a YES or NO. If I pick NO, I will only get results that do not have images (blank/null field). If I pick YES the query will search for any rows WITH a picture string in the field, but I have to be able to extract out what's in that field so that I can refer to the image for later.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work? Not sure if I fully understand..

```
select * from tbl where imageName != '' and imageName != null
```

**Edit**:

> If I pick NO, I will only get results
>   that do not have images (blank/null
>   field). If I pick YES the query will

You will have to check user input and have two queries setup based on the input. Then you should know what fields to pull.

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to do it without adding php-if statements to your sql

```
select (imageName is not null and imageName <> '') as hasImage, other columns from tbl
```